How to Extend time limit response on RDC prompt/message "no action will disconnect your session in 30 seconds" when a user is logged into a PC already
I am able to set time limits "Set a time limit for disconnected sessions" and "Set time limit for active but idle Remote Desktop sessions" via group policy fine but now I am being asked to extend the time limit response when a user is logged into a PC/VM and someone tries to RDP to the same PC and they have 30 seconds to respond to the request if not they will automatically get disconnected.
This is the message that appears on the users screen:

Is it possible to extend this time to 2 minutes or even longer than 30 seconds for the user to respond?
The clients are running Windows 11 version 23H2 and Domain Controllers are running Windows Server 2019 datacenter (were upgraded from Windows Server 2012 R2).
I have tried looking locally on the client and on the DC in group policy a GPO to configure this but I am unable to do so.
I have been searching online seems like the settings maybe configured in Windows registry here:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services 
UPDATE 1
I have come across this setting in Windows registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services
PromptForPasswordTimeout
Having reading on Google seems like this setting is for:
Registry parameter in Windows specifies the amount of time (in seconds) that the system waits for a user to enter their password after a password prompt appears. If the user does not enter the password within this time frame, the prompt will time out, and the system will cancel the operation that required the password.
I was thinking the above could work for this prompt (I know it is not asking for a username or password) but in essence it is prompt (pop up) on Windows system. Configured the setting in registry but still disconnects after 60 seconds.
UPDATE 2
Spoke to Microsoft Support they advised:

Unfortunately, by design, the value is hardcoded and cannot be changed.

Seems like it is not possible (maybe through 3rd party software) logical step it to use GPO where a user is logged in already and to deny other users logging into the same machine.
Will close down the question

Spoke to Microsoft Support they advised:
Unfortunately, by design, the value is hardcoded and cannot be changed.

Seems like it is not possible (maybe through 3rd party software) logical step it to use GPO where a user is logged in already and to deny other users logging into the same machine.
